# Clicking on Sprite doesn't register

Tags: c#, if-statement, sfml.net

I have SFML.NET working fine, and wrote my own little scene manager. In the scene interface I have a method called "Update". I'm trying to see if the user has clicked on the play button or quit button, but I get nothing.

```
    public void Update(RenderWindow window)
    {
        if (Mouse.IsButtonPressed(Mouse.Button.Left))
        {
            Program.WriteDebug("Mouse was clicked.");
            Vector2i mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(window);
            if (play.TextureRect.Contains(mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y))
            {
                // Not displaying text.
                Program.WriteDebug("Play button pressed.");
            }
            else if (quit.TextureRect.Contains(mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y))
            {
                // Not displaying text.
                Program.WriteDebug("Quit button pressed");
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I have the project set to Console Application, so I can see the console and the application.

Comment: I found out that when I change the location of the buttons, the texture rectangle wasn't updating. When I tried to fix it, the button disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **texturerect** as the *global clicking* area:

```
if (play.TextureRect.Contains(mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y))
{
    // Not displaying text, because the texture rect can be something like:
    // width: 100 height: 30 top: 0 left: 0
    // or you don't use it at all and it's all zero (impossible to click)
    Program.WriteDebug("Play button pressed.");
}
```

This is because the texturerect are *local coordinates from the texture* which are say which part of the texture is displaying.
You need to use the **global bounds** of the button:

```
if (play.getGlobalBounds.Contains(mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y))
{
    // should displaying text.
    Program.WriteDebug("Play button pressed.");
}
```

The global bounds are the size and position of the entity including all transformations like rotation and scaling. That's the right one for you.